# adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing... flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, adb

```
adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
* daemon started successfully
List of devices attached
```

when i running flutter. i always got error lost connection. below my flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-arm, locale
    en-ID)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/2.8.1/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (7 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/fahmiaffan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.34.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 97.0.4692.99
```

- Use Mac Apple Silicon M1
- Already install rosetta
- Use brew to install android studio, flutter, android-platform-tools, android-sdk
- I already install sdk api level from android 10 until latest SDK

Or maybe these version of adb still not stable. when i read the release documentation this version crash without any arguments
[image]

I use apple silicon m1 for these devices
[image]

But this strange thing happened when I borrowed my friend's laptop. This macbook pro m1 runs very smoothly. without force close when i starting flutter.

Comment: You have adb multiple times in different versions installed. Don't do this, just use one adb version.  Search your system for all adb binaries, just leave the newest version and replace the other by soft-links to the newest version.

Comment: Nope it's still error till rn. i tried to remove adb from brew and android studio, download the version of adb 32 and 31. still same.

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: honestly i reset my laptop. i think this error populate from conflict when i'm trying to install genymotion